# How do I know what key value pairs are available for deployment manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

For example when I try to figure out what properties I can put into deployment manager for creating a bigquery table, I had to reference the [REST API docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables) as the best place to find parameters and required fields.

Is there a good place from within `gcloud` command or online docs that are specific to deployment manager yamls? I would like to be able to reference required fields and optional fields for creating GCP resources. Currently it's very difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types

You can get a list of the supported resource types by running:
`gcloud deployment-manager types list`

That said the yaml reference from documentation on the that page looks pretty complete.

Edit: Refer to this [github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2) for a list of deployment manager examples.

Answer (score 0):

If anything you need is not described in the documentation/exemplary schemas there is a brutal walk around.

You can make an [api call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) with developer console open (F12) and have a look on network activity where your call will be described with all used and available properties.

It will not provide any addtional information about implementation besides parameter's name itself, so you will have to follow rules covering alike parameter.